# alasql xlsx export problems

Tags: javascript, alasql

I am new to alasql and I would like to export several data in specific cell using alasql,

for example data1 goes do D4, data2 goes to G3, ..., data_n goes to F3

To do that I use the following javascript/alasql code:

```
window.saveFile = function saveFile () {
            var data1 = [{a:"Hi",b:"Hey"},{a:"test",b:"test2"}];
            var data2 = [{a:100,b:10},{a:200,b:20}];
            var opts = [{sourcefilename:"test.xlsx", header:false, range:"D13", sheetid:"RECTO"},{sourcefilename:"test.xlsx", header:false, range:"G4", sheetid:"VERSO"}];
            var res = alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("myxlsx.xlsx",?) FROM ?',[opts,[data1,data2]]);
        }
```

As you can see, I would like my data to go to some specific cell from a sourcefile document (an xlsx file with an empty table)
Theses data would go to D13 and G4 in the sheet named "RECTO" and "VERSO"

However, when I open my output files, I can observe that:

- My output does not look to my sourcefile (I've checked and "test.xlsx" is in my directory)
- My headers are visible even if I put `"header:false"`

If anyone know how to fix my mistakes, it would help me A LOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

header problem is fixed, I replaced `header:` by `headers:` in both " { " brackets and it works, remains the problem of the source file

```
var opts = [{sourcefilename:"test.xlsx", headers:false, range:"D13", sheetid:"RECTO"},{sourcefilename:"test.xlsx", headers:false, range:"G4", sheetid:"VERSO"}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out what was going on. I had an old version of alasql in my project. So I upgrade it and then I found this helpful link where the developers explain how to do it.

```
var data1 = [{a:"Hi",b:"Hey"},{a:"test",b:"test2"}];
var data2 = [{a:100,b:10},{a:200,b:20}];
var opts = [{sourcefilename:"test.xlsx", header:false, range:"D13", sheetid:"RECTO"},
            {sourcefilename:"test.xlsx", header:false, range:"G4", sheetid:"VERSO"}];
var res = alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("myxlsx.xlsx",?) FROM ?',[opts,[data1,data2]],
function(){
done();
});
```

Please checkout this link:
https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/How-to-create-multiple-worksheets-into-a-workbook

Comment: I tried your code and it seems we can't use {header:false} inside a {}, i tried without and nothing change

Comment: try this

    var data1 = [{a:"Hi",b:"Hey"},{a:"test",b:"test2"}];
    var data2 = [{a:100,b:10},{a:200,b:20}];
    var opts = [{sourcefilename:"test.xlsx", header:false, range:"D13", sheetid:"RECTO"},
                {sourcefilename:"test.xlsx", header:false, range:"G4", sheetid:"VERSO"}];
    var res = alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("myxlsx.xlsx",?) FROM ?',[opts,[data1,data2]],
  function(){
    done();
  });

Comment: I tried, export works but sourcefile does not (it sent data to a blank excel)